# Highcharts drill-down using table element as data-source

Tags: highcharts

How Can I create a simple bar drill-down chart while relying on HTML table element as a data-source?

Answer (score 0):

Defaulty you cannot do this by data.js parser, so you need to create your own table parser  to prepare correct structure for highcharts drilldown. I mean create object like series and drilldown.